# How to register routes with different parameter names?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Here is a very simple controller that I will use as an example:

```
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Ok(typeof(int))]
    public IActionResult A([FromRoute] int number)
    {
        return Ok(number);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Ok(typeof(bool))]
    public IActionResult B([FromRoute] bool state)
    {
        return Ok(state);
    }
}
```

In my register routes method, I am saying:

```
 configureRoutes.MapRoute("1", "{controller}/{action}/{number}", new {controller = "Example", action = "A"});
 configureRoutes.MapRoute("2", "{controller}/{action}/{state}", new {controller = "Example", action = "B"});
```

But the issue is while both endpoints can be routed to, only the first route registered can properly retrieve parameters.  In this case, `state` will always be `false`.  If I registered `B` first, `number` would always be `0`.

If I change `number` and `state` to `value`, then it works just fine.  Is there a way that I can have both `number` and `state` in their respective route templates, or is it a requirement that all routes have the same parameter names?  In the case each must have the same name, what would an endpoint with multiple route parameters look like?

Also, I know if I don't mention this someone will suggest it, I am not interested in attribute routing.

Comment: Have you tried adding the expected types to the routes? i.e.: `configureRoutes.MapRoute("1", "{controller}/{action}/{number:int}", new {controller = "Example", action = "A"});`. I assume this also works when you map the routes. I know it works with attribute routing.

Comment: I am curious. Why are you not interested in attribute routing? I can tell you from personal experience that it makes it a lot easier to route stuff. I moved on to it after getting tired of running into issues like this and never looked back.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam: Will there ever be another controller with some action expecting a `number` parameter? Placeholders should be used if you intend the route to match more than one controller/action. This looks pretty specific to me (given the need to match the parameters).

Comment: @insane_developer I think that did the trick.  Do you happen to know where a full list of the constraint types can be found (enums as well would be great)?

Comment: @JuanR the company I work for does not really want to adopt attribute routing, so I am trying to write a tool that uses reflection and the OpenApi schema to map the routes.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) you can see Route Constraints. It's attribute routing documentation, but it applies to what you're doing too.

Comment: @insane_developer thanks, I am new to MVC so that is really helpful.  If you want to leave that as the answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll create an answer later so this can be used as a resource for others with the same issue.

Comment: @Jedi_Maseter_Sam thanks, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the expected types to the routes, i.e.:

```
configureRoutes.MapRoute("1", "{controller}/{action}/{number:int}", new {controller = "Example", action = "A"});
configureRoutes.MapRoute("2", "{controller}/{action}/{state:bool}", new {controller = "Example", action = "B"});
```

Check route constraints [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)